# .bashrc strange warning "lias command not found"

Tags: bash, unix

I have a following `.bashrc` file:

```
function lazygit() {
    git add --all :/
    git commit -a -m "$1"
    git push
}

function bak() {
    git pull
    git add --all :/
    git commit -a -m "backup: $1"
    git push
}
```

But whenever I call `lazygit` or `bak` command, I get:

```
/home/bok/.bashrc: line 1: lias: command not found
Already up-to-date.
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.

nothing to commit, working directory clean
/home/bok/.bashrc: line 1: lias: command not found
Everything up-to-date
```

Why do I get "lias: command not found"?

Comment: What do you aim to do with `:/` in `git add -all`?

Comment: It probably means that you've misspelled `alias` without the initial `a`.

Comment: not related, but remove the `function` keyword and use just `lazygit() { ...` it is better.

Comment: this is whole bashrc, no alias is included in code

Comment: You get those errors when you *call* the `lazygit` and `bak` functions? Not when your shell starts (and `.bashrc` is loaded)? (If so run `set -x; lazygit; set +x` and see what commands are being run up to where the error happens.)

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem A pathspec that starts with a colon starts a "special" pathspec to git. `:/` means "top of working tree" no matter what directory you are in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open `/home/bok/.bashrc` and goto line #1. You will see `lias` and change to `alias` (the `a` was probably accidentally deleted).

Close your terminal completely and re-open it. It should work fine now.

Comment: nothing like this is there, is it possible that there is some other bashrc or is the old version cached somewhere?

Comment: Try the following command `grep -wI "lias" --exclude-dir='.*' ~/.*` It will search all text files in your home directory for the misspelt `lias` command.

Comment: Do you see anything the second time you run it? It should at least show up in your `.bash_history`

Comment: Well, the problem vas I had i misspell in my bashrc on another computer with ss but it is quite strange that this error showed on my computer in that time not connected to other one via ssh.